# What are the dimensions in pixels of a picture taken with iPhone 8 and X?

Tags: photos, camera, iphone

Does anybody know the dimension, in pixels, of a picture taken with the front and back cameras of both iPhone 8 and iPhone X at their maximum resolutions for both cameras?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iPhone X / iPhone 8 Plus / iPhone 8

- 3088 px x 2320 px (FaceTime Camera)
- 4032 px x 3024 px (main cameras)

So the cameras have the same resolution on each model. The wide-angle lenses on the back are all stabilized. iPhone 8 Plus features a telephoto camera which is not stabilized. iPhone X has the same telephoto camera but also sports an optical image stabilization.

Source: [Apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html)